# Setting up a python lab - pip install error VS C++

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-c++, anaconda3

I am following some guides to set up a 'quant stack'.

I installed Anaconda3 and set up an environment and ran it in terminal then ran the following:

`pip install pandas matplotlib matplotlib-inline scipy statsmodels backtrader pyfolio-reloaded quantstats openbb`

Most of it was fine but came into this error:

`bt`

[image]

`linearmodels`

[image]

`rapidfuzz`

[image]

`bottleneck`

[image]

*error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.*

I followed the provided link and installed Visual Studio. I restarted and ran again with same error found. I saw there were many different additional downloads with the VS installer.

My conclusion is there is something I didn't install that is required during the Visual Studio installation but haven't been able to find anything to resolve the missing piece.

I tried several different installation items during the VS install. Does VSCode being on the machine interfere, or previous non Anaconda Pythons being installed to PATH already?

Comment: What link did you follow?

Comment: There are alot of different items that are available to download and I dont want to download something that will cause further problems(if that is possible)
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve, there are some items not compatible with the 3.11python. I removed it from my system and removed the environment in Anaconda I created with the same version. I set it up with python3.9.

As well as install the packages from Microsoft Visual Studio to update the C++ version and ran the pip I first attempted and had 0 errors.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue with Python 3.10+.  I had the exact same issue with 3.10 and 3.11.

Created a new environment in Anaconda Navigator with 3.8.13, ran a Terminal and successfully installed OpenBB with a simple pip install openbb.